# how to take input from a user and run another continuous calculation in parallel while we feed the input, in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Here is my code,

```
import multiprocessing,time

class titan:

    food = 500    
    def foo(self):
        titan.food = titan.food - 10
        print(titan.food, 'food left')
        time.sleep(.5)

    def ask(self):
        if titan.food < 400:
            x = input("give food?")
            if x == 'yes':
                titan.food = titan.food + 100
                print('food refilled!----->>>>', titan.food)
            elif x == 'no':
                print('u making me dead')
            else:
                print('enter valid input')
        elif titan.food == 0:
            print("My time has come !!! +  ")
            break

a = titan()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=a.foo)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=a.ask)

p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

so basically i cant find a way to take the input and keep reducing the food in parallel till it dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `threading` instead of `multiprocessing`.

Here is the edit

```py
import time
from threading import Thread

class titan:

    food = 500    
    def foo(self):
        # maybe you should do a loop here?
        while True:

            # normally, you should alter instance property rather than class property.
            # so it's better to update self.food, rather than titan.food .
            self.food = self.food - 10
            print(self.food, 'food left')
            time.sleep(.5)
            # maybe you want to exit if food is <0?
            if self.food < 0:
                break

    def ask(self):
        # maybe you also want a loop here?
        while True:
            if self.food < 400:
                x = input("give food?")
                if x == 'yes':
                    self.food = self.food + 100
                    print('food refilled!----->>>>', self.food)
                elif x == 'no':
                    print('u making me dead')
                else:
                    print('enter valid input')

            # shouldn't use elif here, because if food < 0,
            # it will also satisfy food<400, 
            # thus the elif block will never be executed.
            if self.food < 0:
                print("My time has come !!! +  ")
                break
       

a = titan()

p1 = Thread(target=a.foo)
p2 = Thread(target=a.ask)
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

The reason `threading` works but not `multiprocessing` in your case is because in `threading` model, two threads can modify the same instance values, while in `multiprocessing`, another process is forked out and a different `titan` instance is created in the other process. The two process will be working on different `titan` instance, thus the food of one instance will not be changed by the other instance.

A few problems:

The two thread will both print to the same screen. If you want p1 thread pause printing while p2 thread is asking for input, you may try to use a simple flag to to pass information between the two thread.

Also, the `input` in p2 thread is blocking if you don't enter a value, thus the program will not exit normally if no value is entered even after food drop below 0.

Comment: @YashikSingh You can add daemon=True when creating p2, thus p2 will not block program exit, and delete the p2.join()